# Flutter debug and release apk are not getting installed on android emulator for testing purpose

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter app and it works fine in debug mode as well as release one also. But my tester is using android emulator to test the app and the issue is apk is not getting installed on the emulator, with a pop up error **App not installed**. minSdkVersion is 16 and targetSdkVersion is 30 and I want my apk to run in android version 5 and above. Can anyone please help with this issue?

Flutter version : 2.2.0
channel: stable

Comment: Maybe you ignore x86 output in ABI Filter in `app\build.gradle `file

Comment: How to ignore x86, also I haven't modified build.gradle.

Comment: see this https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gradle